# How to open working directory of a file showing on iterm2 by mouse?

Tags: macos, iterm2

There is a file showing on iTerm2 screen as below

```
test.txt
```

I want to open working directory of this file using iTerm2. But ⌘-click only opens files but not its working directory on Finder. I do not find any keys or method from iTerm2 to get this.

Comment: pwd command can be used to print working directory in which the file is present

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install bash/zsh themes(depending on what shell you use) that show the current directory in the shell prompt. You can then ⌘-click on that.

- Bash themes(Bash-it): https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it/wiki/Themes
- Zsh themes(oh-my-zsh):
  https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes

Answer (score 1):

You can simply exec `open .` 
It will open the finder from the current directory